# PHP Curl not executing Error 524 Timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout

Curl was working fine previously at my server but when I am trying to run php script having `curl_exec`, I am not able to run the script. It just do processing and returns 524 Timeout error. I have even tried the simplest curl code but still the same problem. When I checked on my local machine it is working fine. Plz help me what can I do. I tried

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "suhailakhtar.xyz");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$fp = fopen('curlerror.log','a');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo($result);
}
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

on a simple curl command and got the error in the file as

```
* Rebuilt URL to: suhailakhtar.xyz/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Trying 31.170.164.150...
* connect to 31.170.164.150 port 80 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to suhailakhtar.xyz port 80: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
```

and also with other url on `Port 443`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was with the server. Port 80 was blocked on my server by hosting provider. I contacted them and get to know about it and requested to make it active. Now everything is working fine as before.